# how to vimeo play button click event?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have point system in my site. Based on the points only I have to show the vimeo video. when play event is fired in vimeo player i need to check whether the user has the sufficient points or not?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need some form of communication with the backend (AJAX) to validate the user's credentials. Even then, you can't PREVENT someone from playing the video on the frontend. It's in their browser, and belongs to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this but, this page http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api suggests, this would do:

```
var iframe = $('#player1')[0],
    player = $f(iframe);
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});

function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
    if(user.points < threshold)
        player.pause();
}
```